# FullTextSearch optional words

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, full-text-search

Using MS SQL 2016 Full Text Search on a table, a user searches for "quick brown fox". This returns no results as all three words do not appear in any single record. But "quick brown" returns results, as does "brown fox" and "quick fox".

Is there a way to construct the input query so words are optional (ie the user says "quick brown *fox" to indicate fox is optional) or for the query itself to return results without all words? I don't mind running two queries, the first for all words, then again for incomplete input if the first returned no rows.

```
string query = String.Concat(@"
    SELECT *
    FROM FullTextSearches AS FT_TBL INNER JOIN
    CONTAINSTABLE(FullTextSearches, (Title, Body), @SearchCondition) AS KEY_TBL
    ON FT_TBL.Id = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
    WHERE (FT_TBL.Accessibility = 0) OR ((FT_TBL.Accessibility & @Roles) > 0)
    ORDER BY KEY_TBL.[RANK] DESC
    OFFSET (@Skip) ROWS FETCH NEXT (@Take) ROWS ONLY");

SqlParameter paramSearch = new SqlParameter("SearchCondition", "\"" + searchTerm + "\"");
SqlParameter paramSkip = new SqlParameter("Skip", pageNumber * pageSize);
SqlParameter paramTake = new SqlParameter("Take", pageSize);
SqlParameter paramRoles = new SqlParameter("Roles", accessibility);
object[] parameters = new object[] { paramSearch, paramSkip, paramTake, paramRoles };
var results = db.FullTextSearch.SqlQuery(query, parameters);
```

Always learning.

Comment: Is that always the case that you will exclude the third word?

Comment: It could be any word(s). Ideally it would return records with all words with a higher ranking than records with only some of the words. Google, for example, states "missing: [word]" in its search results when not all words are found. I don't *have* to have that, just a WIBNI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should get you there. Not multiple queries but multiple joins.

```
string searchTerm = "quick brown *fox"
string withOptional = searchTerm.Replace("*", "");
string withoutOptional = Regex.Replace(searchTerm, "[*]\w", "");

string[] options = new string[]{ withOptional, withoutOptional }; 

string query = String.Concat(@"
    SELECT *
    FROM FullTextSearches AS FT_TBL ");

int i = 1;
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

foreach(string option in options)
{
    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("SearchCondition" + (i++).ToString(), "\"" + option + "\""))
    query += $@"LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(FullTextSearches, (Title, Body), @SearchCondition{i - 1}) AS KEY_TBL{i - 1} ON FT_TBL.Id = KEY_TBL{i - 1}.[KEY] ";
}

SqlParameter paramSkip = new SqlParameter("Skip", pageNumber * pageSize);
SqlParameter paramTake = new SqlParameter("Take", pageSize);
SqlParameter paramRoles = new SqlParameter("Roles", accessibility);
object[] parms = new object[parameters.Length + 3];

for (j = 0; j < parameters.Length; j++)
{
    parms[j] = parameters[j];
}

parms[parms.Length - 3] = paramSkip;
parms[parms.Length - 2] = paramTake;
parms[parms.Length - 1] = paramRoles;

var results = db.FullTextSearch.SqlQuery(query, parms);


string query += String.Concat(@"
    WHERE (FT_TBL.Accessibility = 0) OR ((FT_TBL.Accessibility & @Roles) > 0)
    ORDER BY KEY_TBL.[RANK] DESC
    OFFSET (@Skip) ROWS FETCH NEXT (@Take) ROWS ONLY");
```

Comment: Given that the MS SQL FTS is quite sophisticated I'm surprised there isn't (knowledge of) more flexible search terms. Oh well. Thanks, this is definitely better than my first attempt.

Comment: There may be. Maybe try asking just a query question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ if you really want to get to the bottom of it (knowledge is power). If someone is to know the entire ins and outs of FTS, probably more likely to be there. I answered based on how to tackle from a c# perspective as that is more my specialty than MS SQL features. If you do decide to do that, I'd be interested to know the outcome.